# jQuery unwrap removing the wrong containers

Tags: jquery, html, image, anchor

Obviously a syntax error on my part.

I've got a large quantity of divs where a small amount of them have content wrapped in an anchor. what I'm trying to do is remove the anchors.

thanks for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/rg6n6/

Desired HTML:

```
<div class="box"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></div>
// becomes:
<div class="box"><img src="#"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.box img').unwrap('<a>');
```

Comment: Bookmark the link to jQuery API   http://api.jquery.com/

Top search is filter as you type. Very handy when issues like these arise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.box a img').unwrap()
```

[`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) has no arguments, it simply removes the parent tag of the matched selector. So by selecting the img tag directly under the a, you liberate it from its anchor, as you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.box a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From Jquery Version 3.0 on, you can specifiy a selector.
See [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following javascript:

```
$('.box').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).find('a').html());
});
```